# ChartJS data on x axis and y axis not matching

Tags: laravel, charts

Good Morning. I am trying to draw chart using chartJS where on "x axis - Days of Month" and on "Y axis - total amount". I able to get Days of Months on x axis and for y axis got the total amount. Now i want to show total amount of particular date on same date on x axis. So how can i can compare date on x and y axis and show data.

Say
On "X axis" data is 1 Feb, 2 Feb, 3 Feb, ...... 28 Feb and
On "Y axis" total amount data is = "100" for 2 Feb ,"200" for 4 Feb,"300"....
But while drawing the chart, 200 shows on 1 Feb, 300 for 2 Feb ... Which is wrong.

I hope my question is clear. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you have to assign a `0` value for the dates which doesn't have any amount.

Comment: Yes. It will be a solution, but i am getting "total amount" value from another form where i get date and amount.  How can i add the '0' to dates where i am not inserting the date and amount to table

Comment: populate array after the result of your form and use that populated array instead of direct result of the form.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, I am new to this ... can u give some hint how can i add 0 for date where amount is not entered